# Uncaught (in promise) JavaScript - Skulpt Input Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, promise, skulpt

Im trying to write a Python code editor in browser using Skulpt to execute the Python code and Code Mirror as a text editor.

As the input function for Skulpt uses an alert for input, I have decided to write my own function. The input function I have written works and takes an input from a modal.

```js
Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead,  __future__: Sk.python3, inputfun: function (prompt) {
        clearModal();
        addModalQuestion(prompt);
        toggleModal();
        // the function returns a promise to give a result back later...
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            $("#modal-submit").on("click",function(e){
                // resolve the promise with the value of the input field
                resolve($("#modal-input").val());
            })
        })
        
    }, inputfunTakesPrompt: true});
```

Any errors in the code are usually sent to the output pre:

For normal errors with no input I get this (which is what I want to happen):

[image]

However, when I use an input in my code no error message is output:

[image]

The errors will no longer be displayed and I receive the following error:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how I could resolve this issue or point me in the right direction?

I've put both my skulpt.js and index.html file below if this helps.

SkulptTest.js

```js
// output functions are configurable.  This one just appends some text
// to a pre element.
function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
        throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
        return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}

// Here's everything you need to run a python program in skulpt
// grab the code from your textarea
// get a reference to your pre element for output
// configure the output function
// call Sk.importMainWithBody()
function runit() { 
    var prog = editor.getValue(); ;
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
    Sk.pre = "output";
    Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead,  __future__: Sk.python3, inputfun: function (prompt) {
        clearModal();
        addModalQuestion(prompt);
        toggleModal();
        // the function returns a promise to give a result back later...
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            $("#modal-submit").on("click",function(e){
                // resolve the promise with the value of the input field
                resolve($("#modal-input").val());
            })
        })
        
    }, inputfunTakesPrompt: true}); 
    (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'mycanvas';
    var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
        try {
            if (result = Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true)) {
                    return result;
                }
            
        }
        catch(e) {
            outf(e.toString());
        }
    });
    ;
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--JQuery-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        
        <!--Skulpt-->
        <script src="skulpt/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="skulpt/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        
        <!--Code Mirror-->
        <script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <link href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="codemirror/mode/python/python.js"></script>
        <link href="codemirror/theme/midnight.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!--My Styles-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Data Input</title>
        <meta name="description" content="How do we input data in Python 3?">
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style>
        
            #editor-container {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 47vh;
            }

            #run-container {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 5vh;
                background-color: #0a121f;
            }

            #run-container button {
                float: right;
                height: 5vh;
                width: 15%;
                background-color: yellow;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            #output-container {
                width: calc(100vw - 10px);
                height: calc(45vh - 10px);
                background-color: aliceblue;
                float: right;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }

            #output {
                white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
                white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
                white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
                white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
                word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
            }

        
        </style>
        
        <!--Modal-->
        <link href="css/modal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Skulp-->
        <script src="skulptTest.js"></script>
        
        
        <!--My Code-->
            <div id="right-panel">
                <div id="editor-container">
                    <div class="modal" id="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <span class="close-button"></span>
                            <p id="modal-question" class="modal-question">Input Prompt</p>
                            <input type="text" id="modal-input" name="modal-input" class="modal-input">
                            <button id="modal-submit" class="modal-submit" onclick="toggleModal()">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <div id="run-container">
                    <button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="output-container">
                <pre id="output"></pre>
            </div>
        
        
        <!-- Code Mirror-->
        <script src="js/code-mirror.js"></script>
        <script>editor.setValue("name = input('What is your name?')\nprint(name)");</script>
    </body>
</html>

<script src="js/modal.js"></script>
```

I've also attached a link to all of the files below.

[Code Editor Files](https://filebin.net/9jzgaocooruuv2mv)

If anyone could help me with this I'd really appreciate it

Thanks in advance,

Sean

Comment: Try giving the modal promisifier a dummy catch clause, `return new Promise(.....).catch(e => {});`

Comment: `Sk.pre = "output";` may be correct but `Sk.pre = pre;` would make more sense. You could even try `Sk.pre = $("#output").empty().get(0);`